# How to let users mint your cNFT collection?

Tags: sugar, candymachine, cnft, bubblegum

Is there a counterpart to Solana's Candymachine for minting cNFTs directly from a dApp? If not, what steps should be taken to develop a similar system? Would the process involve uploading collection assets to Arweave, utilizing Bubblegum for cNFT minting, and implementing a web2 architecture for database checks to manage the minting status and progression through the collection's index?

Comment: You can try out Underdog Protocol for minting (https://www.underdogprotocol.com/)